# How do I calculated the expected value of the sum of the greatest (or least) k of n independent uniformly distributed events?

Tags: probability, statistics

This question stemmed from asking myself how to calculate the expected value of the greater or lower of two dice rolls (k=1, n=2) but have phrased it more broadly for the sake of answering a larger question. Simple iterative code gives accurate approximations but I'm sure there's a way to determine a discrete answer that I don't know.

I don't need an exact answer, even guidance on the realm of probability to research would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given independent real-valued random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, you can compute the distribution of their maximum:
$$
P(max_{i=1,\dots,n}X_i \leq x) = P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n{\{X_i \leq x\}}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^nP(X_i \leq x)
$$
and then calculate the expected value.